# What is the difference between "Elliptic Curve Function" and "Hash Functions" like SHA256?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, sha-256

I am reading about bitcoin and I am a little confused about "elliptic curve function" and "SHA256".
Do they have the same properties? Can both be used to generate private and public key pairs?

Comment: SHA256 is a hash function - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function & for ECC look here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography

Comment: Your edit is totally a new question, should be rollback. Changing the course of the question once answered is not an accepted behavior in [so]. What is the input of SHA-256? There is a [short input space problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81652/18298) on the hash functions. Also, there is [no multiplication on ECC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88214/18298), only scalar multiplication.

Comment: Also, if I've understood correctly, you cannot map arbitrarily inputs to point on the curve. The ECC relies on the [discrete logarithm problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298), so we first select a uniform random integer then map it to a point on the curve by the scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 10):

> What is the difference between "Elliptic Curve Function" and "Hash Functions" like SHA256?

There is no real context given, however we can understand it as

- SHA-256 function:

  Yes it is a function, in a rather precise way: a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (collision-resistant hash);

  $$\operatorname{SHA256}:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{256}$$

  - **One way**: it should be practically impossible to invert the given hash digest ( or, Polynomially bounded adversaries cannot revert it).
  - **Deterministic**: the same input must provide the same output.
  - **Random**: we should not know the hash of input before hashing it. We can read this as hash functions are candidates for Random Oracles (RO) and SHA256 is not since it has a length extension attack, SHA3 and Blake2 are more close to RO.
  - has **Pre-image resistance**: close to one way; given a hash value $h$ it must be infeasible for polynomial-time adversaries to find input $m$ such that $\operatorname{SHA256}(m) = h$.
  - **Second Pre-image resistance**: given a message $m$ and it's hash value $h$, find another message $m'$ such that $\operatorname{SHA256}(m) = h = \operatorname{SHA256}(m')$.
  - and **Collision resistance**; find the distinct input messages $m_1 \neq m_2$ such that $\operatorname{SHA256}(m_1) = \operatorname{SHA256}(m_2)$.

  Bitcoin uses double SHA256 (SHA256d) and [SHA256d is secure against the length extension attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87434/18298).
- Elliptic Curve function:

  **This is strange naming, is it the L-function of the Elliptic curves or what?** Since the question is talking about Bitcoin, it should rather be the set of functions that Elliptic curves provide more than the below functions:

  - **Addition** as the group operation (addition, negation, inverse, commute, and association).
  - **Scalar multiplication**: given a base point $G$ and add it $t$ times:

    $$[t]G : = \underbrace{G + G + \cdots + G}_{t-times}
    $$
  - **Public key generation**: Select random $k$ and calculate $[k]G$.
  - [**ECDSA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) signature generation.
  - **ECDSA** signature validation.

Now the answers to your other question are clear.

> Do they have the same properties?

No, they don't! Even one is a function the other is a set of functions.

> Can both be used to generate private and public key pairs?

No.

However, one can use SHA256 to digest an entropy source to select the random $k$ for their private key and find their public key $K = [k]G$ by using the scalar multiplication of the Elliptic Curves.

And the Bitcoin Address is calculated as;

$$\text{Bitcoin Adress} = \operatorname{RIPEMD160(SHA256(}K))$$ as 20-byte adresses ([RIPEMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD)).

---

**Special note:** Some blockchain books/websites use EC multiplication for EC scalar multiplication, like Antonolopus's book Mastering Bitcoin, page 68. This confuses many since they start to think that $P\cdot Q$ exists. No! EC forms additive Abelian groups, and with the scalar multiplication (the usual way to define for additive groups) they form a [Z-Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Examples), nothing more.

Comment: +1.  I would have said they're like comparing apples and orangutans, but you took the extra effort to describe the properties of apples and the properties of orangutans in a way that should help the OP research the topic, and potentially form a more exacting question in the future.  Great Stack Exchange form!

Comment: @CortAmmon the OP did not specify the source, however, I've seen that many sites and books cause confusion. See the newly added special note with an example.

Comment: We'll exclude hash-based signatures for now I guess. If you count those they you can also do message authentication, key derivation and random number generation "with a hash function".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sure they exist. I want to keep the answer in the context of bitcoin. And the hash functions are ubiquitous as we listed some [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64588/18298). Do you know that used in bitcoin?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes blockchains now is a wide subject that I've might miss one that use...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes is there a specific reason to be removed from HNQ? Seen now while looking OP's edits.

Answer (score 1):

Both are functions. it means they are relations between two sets (the input set and the output set) such that every elements $x$ of the input set is in relation with at most one element of the output set. This element is called the image of $x$.

But they do not have the same status in cryptography. Function in "elliptic curve function" is a way to describe an elliptic curve. If the function is $f$, the points of the curve are $(x, f(x))$.

SHA-256, is an algorithm (an algorithm is more precise than a function, because it indicates how compute the images) which is used to generate *hashes*.

To generate the private key, we pick uniformly at random an integer $n$ of $256$ bits.

To generate the public key we multiply a generator $G$ (given as a public parameter of the curve) by $n$ (by using the square-and-multiply procedure). It gives us a point of the curve $P$. Sometimes this $P$ is considered as a hash of the private key. But it is much more than a simple a hash, it's a public key. It verifies much more properties than usual hash functions such as SHA-256.

If you want more details, you can look :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_digital_signature_algorithm

Comment: If SHA256 is irreversible or preimage resistant. Why bitcoin just don't use the SHA256 to generate a public key out of a randomly generated private key instead of elliptic curve multiplication. I know the input of SHA256 can be anything and output can be 0 to 2^256. Can someone explain to me the elliptic curve multiplication or function whatever is it in the sense of input and output just like SHA256. Because I am not able to understand it from Wikipedia. I have tried it several times.

Comment: Preimage resistance is not enough. You need to sign, it's much more difficult to make, a simple hash function is not enough. Eliptic curve are not basic maths, you can try to read this: cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/